# Session cookie not used after authentication using hidden iframe [OAuth2 / OpenID Connect]

Tags: authentication, cookies, iframe, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We want to provide SSO to one of our external partners and have implemented this using OAuth2 and OpenID Connect. The basics are:

- An `authorize` endpoint for the authorization (`api.server.com`). If authorized the result is a redirection location for the login page (if not logged in yet) or the client specified `redirect_uri` with the authorization code that the client can use to request access tokens for our API. Note that we don't use return status 302 (Found) as we want to handle the redirects in code. Instead we return 204 (No Content).
- An `authenticate` endpoint for the user authentication (`portal.server.com`). If authentication is successful we request the authorization code and this is returned using the client specified `redirect_uri`. Authentication failures will not leave the authentication page.
- When a user is properly authenticated a session cookie is returned to the browser with `SameSite=strict`, `Secure` and `HttpOnly`. The domain of the session cookie is set to `portal.com` with `Path=/`.
- The API server also provides an endpoint with iframe source code that the client can include. The iframe handles the communication between the client and API. Because the iframe uses the same domain as the API server the session cookie should be sent with any XHR request to the API server.

I have implemented a simple client application that:

- Has some form fields to query the relevant data (client ID, redirect URI, etc) for the `authorize` call. A simple button will start the authorization process.
- Includes the iframe.
- Uses `postMessage` to pass the data to the iframe.
- Defined a message handler to handle messages posted by the iframe.

Say that the client runs on the domain `client.com` and when I start the client and inspect the requests using a new private browser window I see the following:

- The `authorize` endpoint is called and because we are not logged in yet returns a 204 with the `authenticate` endpoint of the portal.
- The iframe uses `postMessage` to return this to the client and the client performs the redirection to the `authenticate` endpoint.
- The user logs in and will request the authorization code from the server using the `authorize` endpoint.
- As the user is now logged in, we return a 204 with the client supplied `redirect_uri` and the authorization code
- The return is handled by the portal code and redirects to the given location.

This is correct behavior.

However, when I start the client application within the same window again and fill in the correct data, I would expect the `authorize` endpoint to return the client supplied `redirect_uri` and the authorization code as we are already logged in.

Instead I still get back the `authenticate` endpoint and upon inspection the `authorize` endpoint is called but the session cookie is not sent along with it.

My question is why is the session cookie not included? Also using `SameSite=Lax` doesn't work and `SameSite=None` is not an option here.

For completeness the iframe source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Client Authorization</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    async function receiveMessage(e) {
        try {
            // Check the origin of the message
            if (e.origin !== "https://client.com") throw("invalid origin");
            
            const authUrl = buildUrl(e.data);
            const response = await fetch(authUrl);

            if (response.status === 204) {
                // redirect url returned as Location header
                const location = await response.headers.get("location");
                e.source.postMessage({
                    type: "redirect",
                    location: location,
                }, e.origin);
            } else {
                throw("call failed");
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            e.source.postMessage({
                type: "error",
                error: error,
            }, e.origin);
        }
    }
    
    function serialize(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            }
        }
        
        return str.join("&");
    }

    function buildUrl(options) {
        return "https://api.server.com/authorize?" + serialize(options);
    }
    
    // Add event listener for messages
    window.addEventListener("message", async (e) => { await receiveMessage(e); }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```